# How to hide borders of combox and only show the bottom border in MFC?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm want to make a flat design ComboBox which only shows a blue bottom border. But I can only change 4 borders' color. How to hide right,left and top border and show bottom border?

Comment: Just custom-draw it.

Comment: You cannot [custom-draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-custom-draw) a combo box. Combo boxes support only [owner-drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-an-owner-drawn-combo-box). I don't know whether that allows you to customize the appearance of the combo box itself (as opposed to the drop-down list).

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you need to draw the entire control by yourself. You need to [subclass the control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-window-procedures?redirectedfrom=MSDN#subclassing-a-window) and paint the border.

Comment: After we struggled a lot with attempting to do such things (also with other controls like edit controls) I can tell you, there's no easy way to solve this... Sorry! :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it. Just rewrite `OnPaint()` function and use `CDC::DrawEdge(CRect, BDR_RAISEDINNER, BF_BOTTOM)` to drwa a bottom border.

```
void CCustomComboBox::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);
    dc.DrawEdge(rc, BDR_RAISEDINNER, BF_BOTTOM);

    ...   //draw other parts of ComboBox
}
```